# API GET request wont allow query string due to error

Tags: python, api, python-requests, syntax-error

I'm attempting to make an API get to grab some data in .json format.

When I run the request, I'm getting a syntax error within the API address. below is the code I'm attempting to run.

I can make a basic request against the parent site and receive a <Response [200]> and I've sent get requests here without any issues in the past.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
pv_data = requests.get("https://api.patentsview.org/uspc_mainclasses/query?q={"_and":[{"_contains":{"uspc_mainclass_id":["800","424","514","506","435","436","536"]}},{"_gt"{"patent_date":"2009-12-31"}},{"_lt":{"patent_date":"2021-04-01"}}]}&f=["assignee_city","assignee_country","assignee_latitude","assignee_longitude","assignee_num_patents_for_uspc_mainclass","assignee_organization","assignee_total_num_patents","forprior_country","forprior_date"]")
```

...and the response

```
  File "<ipython-input-31-0b6aea36e1fe>", line 1
pv_data = requests.get("https://api.patentsview.org/uspc_mainclasses/query?q={"_and":[{"_contains":{"uspc_mainclass_id":["800","424","514","506","435","436","536"]}},{"_gt"{"patent_date":"2009-12-31"}},{"_lt":{"patent_date":"2021-04-01"}}]}&f=["assignee_city","assignee_country","assignee_latitude","assignee_longitude","assignee_num_patents_for_uspc_mainclass","assignee_organization","assignee_total_num_patents","forprior_country","forprior_date"]")
                                                                               ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That long line of code is too unreadable which resulted to you having a lot of problems with the usage of " and '. Pep8 suggests a maximum length of just 80 https://pep8.org/#maximum-line-length while yours is a whopping 450+ :) I would suggest to use temporary holders (I mean variables) to each of your query parameters. It can actually even solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using double quotes inside the url string as well, the interpreter takes whatever is between the first 2 instances of the `"` characters as a valid string and it doesn't know what to do with the rest.

You could avoid this error by having the starting quotes be like this `'`:

```
pv_data = requests.get('https://api.patentsview.org/uspc_mainclasses/query?q={"_and":[{"_contains":{"uspc_mainclass_id":["800","424","514","506","435","436","536"]}},{"_gt"{"patent_date":"2009-12-31"}},{"_lt":{"patent_date":"2021-04-01"}}]}&f=["assignee_city","assignee_country","assignee_latitude","assignee_longitude","assignee_num_patents_for_uspc_mainclass","assignee_organization","assignee_total_num_patents","forprior_country","forprior_date"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the python got confused which double quotes(`"`) should be used to end the string. One solution is to escape all the inner `"` with `\`.

But I would suggest you to use the `request` API itself to handle the query paraments.
From the documentation you can pass `params` keyword argument to send the data to the URL.

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
```

You can see that the URL has been correctly encoded by printing the URL:

```
>>> print(r.url)
https://httpbin.org/get?key2=value2&key1=value1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use different type of quotation mark, single = ' , double = " , or triple = ''' wich let you write the same sentence on different line.

```
'''
this is a code
'written'
on
"different"
line
'''
```